# Vinyl-FTP encountering `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` error. FileZilla works fine. Anyone know a fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, gulp, vinyl-ftp

I am trying to use Gulp to FTP files from my local to a remote shared server site, however, I get the error:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ftps.mysite.com ftps.mysite.com:21
>       at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)

Googling for solutions I see that this is a common issue with using the `\` character in the username, but my username is does not have that.

My code on my gulpfile.js is:

```
gulp.task('ftp-deploy', function() {

    var conn = ftp.create({
      host:     'ftps.mysite.com',
      port:     21,
      user:     'me@mysite.com',
      password: 'mypassword123',
      parallel: 10,
      log:      gutil.log,
    });

    var localFilesGlob = ['css-dist/**']; 

    return gulp.src(localFilesGlob, { base: './css-dist/', buffer: false })
      .pipe( conn.newer( '/css' ) )
      .pipe( conn.dest( '/css' ) )
    ;

});
```

I tried replacing `@` with `%40` but that made no difference.

Would anyone know how I could fix this? Is there perhaps another way I should be writing `@` to work as a string in JS?

Comment: Show us verbose FileZilla log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a proper answer as I don't understand why this works, but it started working after I deleted

```
port:     21,
```